# Bernoulli principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

I've been trying to deduce the Bernoulli's theorem but i have a few problems
[image]

Why is it restricted to a streamline?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you could be very clear about the concept of streamline that would be really helpful as well =)

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. Please do not post images of text, instead type the content of the image (If the problem is how to type the maths: [On Physics.SE you can typeset equations using MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation). This way the content will be accessible to people with visual impairments, the search function of the site and search engines, in addition creating a more consistent look.

Comment: You do realize that U has the same direction as a unit vector in the streamline direction, correct?  So the dot product of the unit vector with the gradient of the kinetic energy per unit volume gives you the spatial rate of change of the kinetic energy per unit volume with respect to distance along a streamline.

Comment: Bernoulli equation hold along either a streamline or a vortex line. Part of my post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410701/torricellis-law-and-variable-density/410836#410836) may be useful to you.

Comment: It is just energy conservation. But if it not streamline motion then energy will not be conserved. Hence we can not use it.